# Bash regex match after @

Tags: regex

I want to match a string after @
For example : 
stringZ="-p 2234 root@tor"

the result would be "tor"

The best I managed to do is : 
echo `expr match "$stringZ" '\(.*\@\)'`
which output: 
-p 2234 root@
How can I negate this?

Comment: use capturing groups `.*\@(.*)` and print the index 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the `bash` builtin string modification functionality:

```
echo "${stringZ##*@}"
```

Doesn't even require a regex, because, really what you are trying to do doesn't need one...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`:

```
echo '-p 2234 root@tor' | sed -r 's/.*@//'
```

Or if you had it in the `stringZ` variable:

```
newstring=$(echo stringZ | sed -r 's/.*@//')
echo $newstring
```

Comment: the `sed` is fine, but why catching something that you print later on? `sed -r 's/.*@//'` suffices, because it removes everything up to `@`, so the remaining string is what you want.

Comment: @fedorqui absolutely. Lack of sleep to blame.